# Working at 2 WORKDIR simultaneously DOCKEFILE

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to reduce the buildtime for my docker image.

I have to install node dependency for backend and bower dependency from UI.

Right now it runs sequentially from 2 different workdir.

```
WORKDIR $CLIENT_DIR
RUN bower --allow-root install

WORKDIR $SERVER_DIR
RUN npm install
```

Since both are independent on each other, its annoying to wait for bower install to finish for installing npm install.

I think docker will have  better way to handle such cases.

I think my question is clean, and doesn't need more info. Please let me know if I should provide some other infor as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since docker is building its images in layers, you will not be able to run this dockerfile as it is in parallel.
Here are 2 workarounds I can think of that might allow for parallelism, but IMO are a bigger effort than the value they will give you -

1. You can run both commands in the background, and then execute a bash script that checks if the processes have finished their work.
2. You can leverage multistage build by building 2 images - one with your npm dependencies and another with bower dependencies, and then get a third build which gets the artifacts created by the 2 previous builds.

Comment: can you please show me an example, i am actually not clear about `and then get a third build which gets the artifacts created by the 2 previous builds.`